# Django: including prefetched objects in values() dict

Tags: django, orm, prefetch

I would like to create a dict or dict-like object based on a django orm query involving prefetched objects. Due to the number of objects involved, I would like to do as much of this in the database as possible.

To use the familiar example structure, if I have an Author and Books with the usual ForeignKey from Book to Author, and I also have an Edition with a ForeignKey back to Book, I would like to do something like

```
Author.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('book_set', queryset=Book.objects.filter(cycle__id=3).select_related('edition__binding'), to_attr="bindings"))  # clearly this is wrong
```

and ultimately call `.values()` or something of the sort to get a dict-like result consisting of rows of authors, which should include an entry "bindings", which contains a list of bindings that each author has been published in. The stretch goal would be to have bindings be a semicolon-separated list, ie `[{"Author": "Daniel Dennett", "bindings": "paper; hardback; cloth"}, {"Author": "Jemiah Jefferson", "bindings": "paper; zine"}]`

So far, I have been able to get a field like "bindings" attached to the queryset using prefetch_related and select_related, as above, but this field is not included in the result of a call to `.values()`. This means I have to loop over the objects, which simply takes too long for my purposes (there are many objects, and the request times out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom a `Concat` annotation which will mimic `MySQL` `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Then you can use `.values` on the annotated `bindings`.

For Django 1.8 your `Concat` class can be something like this:

```
from django.db import models
class Concat(models.Aggregate):
    # supports GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT field SEPARATOR str_val)
    # do not support order_by
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(expressions)s SEPARATOR "%(separator)s")'
    def __init__(self, expression, distinct=False, separator=None, **extra):
        super(Concat, self).__init__(
            expression,
            distinct='DISTINCT ' if distinct else '',
            separator=separator or '',
            output_field=models.CharField(),
            **extra)
```

While in `Django 1.7`

```
class Concat(models.Aggregate):
    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        #we send source=CharField to prevent Django from casting string to int
        aggregate = SQLConcat(col, source=models.CharField(), is_summary=is_summary, **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate

#for mysql
class SQLConcat(models.sql.aggregates.Aggregate):
    sql_function = 'group_concat'
    @property
    def sql_template(self):
        if self.extra.get('separator'):
            return '%(function)s(%(field)s SEPARATOR "%(separator)s")'
        else:
            return '%(function)s(%(field)s)'
```

Now you can do:

```
Author.objects.annotate(bindings=Concat('book__edition__binding')).values('name', 'bindings')
```

unfortunately this wont filter your `books` by `cycle__id=3`, but you can apply the filter before the annotation happens.

```
Author.objects.filter(book__cycle__id=3).annotate(bindings=Concat('book__edition__binding')).values('name', 'bindings')
```

This will strip from the result `authors` without `book` with `cycle__id=3`.